# Continue queries after an aggregation with Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a complex aggregation I use to sort data and I want to be able to continue my query after. I'm able to do the aggregation and returns an array with models but, because it is an array, I can't continue my query. Here is my example :

```
aggregation = [
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"domain_test#interventions",
    "localField":"_id",
    "foreignField":"identity_id",
    "as":"interventions"
  }},
  {"$addFields":{
    "sortorder":{
      "$let":{
        "vars":{"intervention":{"$arrayElemAt":["$interventions",0]}},
        "in":{"$indexOfArray":[[true,false],"$$intervention.closed"]}
      }
    }
  }},
  {"$match": identities.selector },
  {"$sort":{"sortorder":-1, "screenname": 1}},
]

identities = identities.collection.aggregate(aggregation).map do |document|
  Identity.instantiate(document)
end
```

At this point, I'm not able to do `identites.where(something_else: true)` because it's an array.

I tried to do `Identity.find(identities.map(&:id))` but the order is not respected.

Is it possible to do what I want?

Comment: you can't execute `where` queries on an array, if you need to do it you should do it before you do a `map` on the result

Comment: I know I can't do a `where` on an array but my question is "How to continue to chain queries after an aggregation". I want to do something like : `Identity.my_complex_sorting_with_aggregation.where(something: true).count`.

Comment: You can add the `$match` stage in the aggregation pipeline before you get the results back to client. Is that what you are asking ?

Comment: I don't think you can do a where after you aggregation, you should supply your where condition in the aggregate using something like `something: { $eq: true } }`

Comment: @Veeram I already use `$match` in my query. I want to use the aggregation like we use a `Mongoid::Criteria` in ruby.